# Difference print out between Thermal Printer and Dot-Matrix

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, dot-matrix

can you help me for this problem..?

I use library [mike42](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) for printing receipt..
the device I used :

1. Printing receipt with Thermal Printer Panda PRJ-080B
2. Printing receipt with Dot Matrix EPSON LQ-2190

in this case, alignment text is not same
[this is result of printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7pGz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the pitch on the button located on the thermal printer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved..

make specific pitch setting on your Dot-matrix..

> **Change PS Pitch to Specific Pitch (ex : 10 cpi, 12 cpi, etc)**